# Explanation needed for a statement about power series convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I got a task in front of me but I don't really understand it. If someone could explain, I think I would be able to solve it myself.

> $P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k}$ is a power series. There exists a $k_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ with $a_{k} \neq 0$ for all $k \geq k_{0}$.
>
> Proof that: If the sequence $\left ( \left | \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}} \right | \right )_{k \geq k_{0}}$ converges towards a number in $\mathbb{R}$ or towards $\infty$ and if $a:= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left | \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}} \right | \in \mathbb{R} \cup \left \{ \infty \right \}$ indicates this limit point ($\infty $ or $-\infty$) then following applies for the radius of convergence $R$ of $P$:
>
> $R=\left\{\begin{matrix}
> 0, & a = \infty\\ 
> \infty, & a = 0 \\ 
> \frac{1}{a}, & otherwise 
> \end{matrix}\right.$

---

What is meant by $k_{0}$ ? It's just any unknown variable which seems to be smaller or equal $k$, right? Oh and it cannot be smaller than zero.

What is $a_{k}$ ? It's just any sequence that cannot be zero, right?

So first I take the sequence $a_{n}$, use the ratio test to see if it converges. Okay after that is done, I check if in the ratio test, I get + or - $\infty$.

Is it right so far?

But what confuses me most is this:

> $a:= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left | \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}} \right | \in \mathbb{R} \cup \left \{ \infty \right \}$

What is it saying with infinity?

Sorry I haven't started with the task but first I try to understand everything, then start.

Comment: What are *exactly* the hypotheses on the power series? It's false for polynomial, for instance (a polynomial is a particular type of power series).

Comment: @Bernard: His second paragraph gives the condition that does not allow any polynomial.

Comment: @user21820: You mean the ratio test? This excludes also a lot of series which are not polynomials.

Comment: @Bernard: His question says "There exists a $k_0∈\mathbb{N}$ with $a_k≠0$ for all $k≥k_0$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Since you've gotten explanation of the notation already, here's the sketch of how to prove the result. Radius of convergence means that the power series converges for anything **strictly** inside. So if $|x| = r < \frac1a$, then let $s$ be such that $r < s < \frac1a$, and so as $k \to \infty$ eventually $|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}| \to a$ and hence $|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}| < s^{-1}$, which by induction gives $|a_{m+k}| < |a_m| s^{-k}$ for every natural $k$ where $m$ is some (sufficiently large) constant natural number. Therefore for any natural $q \ge p \ge m$ we have $| \sum_{k=p}^q a_k x^k | \le \sum_{k=p}^\infty |a_k| r^k = \sum_{k=p}^\infty |a_m| s^{m-k} r^k = |a_m| s^m \sum_{k=p}^\infty |a_m| (\frac{r}{s})^k$ which is finite since $\frac{r}{s} < 1$. Thus by Cauchy convergence the original power series converges.

Comment: Wow I didn't expect it's gonna be that complicated, also didn't expect it will be done via induction proof.
So your "hint" is basically the proof for the first of three things? Complete proof for $\frac{1}{a}$?

Comment: @element115: The last you mean, specifically the "otherwise" case in your question. The other two cases should be easier. This is a standard theorem, and the same technique works to prove the general formula for radius of convergence (which you can find at wikipedia).

Comment: Ok last question, what does $s$ stand for here? 
Is it my $k_{0}$?
Thank you very much!

Comment: @element115: $s$ is simply something in-between $r$ and $\frac1a$. It has nothing to do with $k_0$. You can try following the same method but using $r$ or $\frac1a$ instead of $s$; you'll find that the proof will fail. Only picking a real in-between works.

Answer (score 5):

"What is meant by $k_0$ ? It's just any unknown variable which seems to be smaller or equal k, right? Oh and it cannot be smaller than zero."
  No. $k_0$ is a constant, not a variable.  This is saying that $a_k$ is non-zero for all $a_k$ in the sequence with k larger than $k_0$.

"What is $a_k$? It's just any sequence that cannot be zero, right?"
 No. "$a_k$" is the "kth" term in this given sequence, not the sequence itself.

"So first I take the sequence $a_n$, use the ratio test to see if it converges. Okay after that is done, I check if in the ratio test, I get + or - ∞".

Is it right so far?"
"+ or - ∞"?  The ratio test says that a series converges if the ratio goes to a number less that 1, diverges if larger than 1.

"But what confuses me most is this:

$a:=limk→∞∣∣\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}∣∣∈R∪{∞}$
What is it saying with infinity?"
 What that is saying is that "a" can be any real number or it could be infinity.  In other words, it could be anything!

Comment: Thank you for answer. At the beginning, when I'm supposed to proof that the power series converges / diverges using the ratio test, how can I do it if the series isn't even given? All I know is the series is $a_{k}$. But that's nothing to work with, is it...?